# Customer support software which is able to associate tickets with our equipment

Tags: project-management, crm, support-tracker

I wonder if anyone has some good suggestions for a software package that we can purchase and customise to meet our needs.

Here's the situation:

- My company produces sensor systems that we sell around the world to our customers.
- We also usually have support agreements in place to monitor, maintain these pieces of equipment.

So, I'm hoping we can find something out there that will let us get to a point where:

1. When we get support requests, we should be able to create a ticket/case for that request and that should be associated with the customer, but also the piece of equipment they own.
2. Should then be able to look up all tickets (open/closed) for a customer, or piece of equipment.
3. Should know which pieces of equipment each customer has (so if I'm entering a ticket for a customer I don't have to choose from a dropdown with 1000 entries in it).
4. Should let us record the configuration of a piece of equipment, and ideally search across them (e.g. find all equipment at version X.X of software across all customers).
5. Would be great to have further CRM features - customer details, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what we can do here?

Answer (score 3):

We use [Eventum](https://launchpad.net/eventum) for customer support ticket tracking. It is an open-source, web-based platform, built on top of PHP and MySQL (thus easy to extend / customize). Unfortunately, as I am only a user and not an admin / developer, I cannot tell you how much functionality you get "out of the box", nor how much customization we've done for our specific needs.

- When we get support requests, we should be able to create a ticket/case for that request and that should be associated with the customer, but also the piece of equipment they own. *I can confirm this works.*
- Should then be able to look up all tickets (open/closed) for a customer, or piece of equipment. *Another check-mark.*
- Should know which pieces of equipment each customer has (so if I'm entering a ticket for a customer I don't have to choose from a dropdown with 1000 entries in it). *We have customized something similar.*
- Should let us record the configuration of a piece of equipment, and ideally search across them (e.g. find all equipment at version X.X of software across all customers). *Almost sure it can be achieved.*
- Would be great to have further CRM features - customer details, etc. *Same as the former.*

Looking at the website, I'm a little bit concerned about the fact that their [wiki](http://eventum.wikinet.org/) is no longer up. However, you should be able to get in touch with the developers. The project was started under the [MySQL umbrella](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/sources.html) (they are, or at least were, using it internally for their own issue tracking needs), not sure what is their relationship with Launchpad at this moment.

I found some more info [here](http://mysql.localhost.net.ar/downloads/other/eventum/screenshots.html); check the *related pages* on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you have specific requirements, such as what you listed in your question, it's best (and easiest) to get a recommendation from an unbiased expert. This software product selection tool actually recommends the best software solution for you based on the specific needs of your work.

If you want to check it out, you can find it here:
http://technologyadvice.com/crm/smart-advisor/

Comment: If you're associated in any way with technologyadvice.com, you must disclose it in your answer - a simple "I work for company FooBar" is enough. Thanks, and welcome to the site!